# What is the best correlation coefficient to use in order to compare how similar two second degree polynomial functions are?

Tags: correlation, polynomial

This will likely be a lament question, but then again I am a lament in the area of statistics. Please accept my apologies for that in advance. :)

Suppose you have 2 data sets:

Dataset 1:
some values that can be represented by a second degree polynomial 4x^2 + 5x + 42

Dataset 2:
some values that can be represented by a second degree polynomial 3x^2 + 5x + 4

If I want to compare how statistically close the curves (THE CURVES, MEANING THE DELTAS, THE DIFFERENCE IN THE WAY THE VALUES CHANGE, NOT COMPARING THE ABSOLUTE VALUES) of those 2 functions are, what correlation coefficient would give the most accurate results? Pearson? Spearman or something else?

So for functions y = 3x^2 + 5x + 4 and y = 3x^2 + 5x + 1 the correlation coefficient should be 1.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by 'best', I'd say Spearman,

Comment: You give formulas rather than data sets.  Could you explain the sense in which these formulas describe data sets?  That might help understand what you're looking for.

Comment: @whuber consider the following two data sets: 4, 12, 26, 46, 104 and 1, 9, 23, 43, 101 which correspond to the following two second degree polynomial functions: y = 3x^2 + 5x + 4 and y = 3x^2 + 5x + 1 Now, since the curves of those 2 functions are the SAME the correlation coefficient should be 1, as the curves are the same, and the only thing different is that one of them is slightly higher on the y-axis than the other.

Comment: The curves do not have correlation coefficients, but the data do.  Compute the correlation of the data.